# Invoke Child method(and pass data) from parent, Child will be dynamically loaded component(router-outlet or lazy loaded child) in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

The child components are lazy loaded components so

<router-outlet #child >

### parent

"child.childMethod()"

this is not working ,Could you please someone help me to call child method from parent component also how I can pass data from/to between child and parent component
this will be like master layout and different child components scenario.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of angular, using `child.childMethod()` wont be possible when lazy loading a component that way, because the parent isn't aware of what it will load.

If you're trying to trigger the `childMethod()` multiple time, using a service may be an option.

It will be provided in the `parent`, which you'll then be able to use in the `child` one.

Then you may trigger the `childMethod()` by subscribing it to a provider from the `parentService`

```js
// parent.module.ts
providers: [
  ParentService
]
```

```js
// parent.service.ts
  triggerChildMethod$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(null)
```

```js
// parent.component.ts
constructor(private _parentService: ParentService) {}

childMethod() {
 this._parentService.next(true);
}
```

```js
// child.component.ts
constructor(private _parentService: ParentService) {}

ngOnInit() {
 this._parentService
      .pipe(
        filter((event) => (typeof event === "boolean" ? true : false)), // Avoid triggered on instantiating
        takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll), // Do not forget to unsubscribe
      )
      .subscribe((value) => {
         this.childMethod() // Here you are
      })
}
```

Comment: Thank you Raphael ,Let me try this

Comment: @Aja Did it worked, would you need more help on that ?